# Access --net-aliased service from Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-network

I've created a Docker network with

```
docker network create test
```

and instanced a couple of services with

```
--net test --net-alias somealias
```

but my frontend container running on the same network can't find the address by just asking for "somealias". If I run an interactive Python3 interpreter and call

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen("somealias").read()
```

there's a `ValueError: unknown url type`. Accessing some address like `https://stackoverflow.com` does just fine. Is there some kind of prefix I'm missing? I've tried http and https but neither does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am dumb. urllib.request.urlopen tries to open a HTTP connection, but obviously that won't work with a DNS name. To get the IP address, you should do

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname("my-server")
```

and that will resolve the IP address for you.